# get context in googlemapsactivity

Tags: android, android-intent

I tried to use `GoogleMapsActivity`. In this case, when current location gets close to correct point activity must start other activity. I read much articles and i found this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent("fto.behapp.Locations");
intent.putExtra("situations",Integer.parseInt(valid));
intent.putExtra("ring",true);
intent.putExtra("type",1);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setClass(context, Locations.class);
intent.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED +
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD +
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON +
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
toast("inside");
startActivity(intent);
```

But i don't have any `context` to set intent class and i can't use `this`, anybody have idea how i can fix this?

Comment: an activity **is** a context

Comment: Use `YourActivityClass.this`.

Comment: what? how can i call this when its googlemap fragmen?

Comment: You can call the `activity` via `getActivity` method. `getActivity()` in a Fragment returns the Activity

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getApplicationContext()` if you are in activity. or you can you use `getContext()` if you are in fragment.